# mybatis spring ref cursor mapping

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures, mybatis

I am using mybatis-spring and trying to map a ref cursor from oracle. The result is coming back as null. Any ideas please?

```
<select id="check" parameterType="myVO" 
        resultMap="VOResultMap" statementType="CALLABLE" resultType="object">
{ call MYPKG.proc_check(
        #{myVO.id, javaType=String, jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN},
        #{myVO, mode=OUT, javaType=ResultSet, jdbcType=CURSOR, resultMap=VOResultMap}
)}
```

SP:

```
PROCEDURE proc_check (        
    p_id IN VARCHAR2, po_outCursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN        
        OPEN po_outCursor FOR 
            SELECT * FROM MYTABLE; 
END;
```

Map:

```
<resultMap id="VOResultMap" type="myVO">
    <result property="action" column="ACTION" />
    <result property="id" column="ID" />
    <result property="name" column="NAME" />
</resultMap>
```

DAO:

```
public MyVO check(@Param("VO") MyVO myVO);
```

Usage:

```
MyVO myVO = new MyVO(id);
MyVO obj = myDAO.check(myVO);
// obj is null !!
```

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

OK, from the java side you need to use a map.

In the xml set parameterType="java.util.Map"
In Java put the "in" parameter i.e. map.put("id", identifier);

The interface can now return void.
Then call the interface, like myDAO.check(myMap);

The after call myMap.get("myVO"), and you will get back a List.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just clarifying the answer provided in the above post.

You need to define the map same as bean class members, this is to make sure the refcursor columns gets auto mapped to the properties in map and the list of bean objects.

Mapper.xml

```
    <select id="check"  
            parameterType="java.util.Map" 
            resultMap="VOResultMap" statementType="CALLABLE">
        { call MYPKG.proc_check(
            #{id, javaType=String, jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN},
            #{myVO, mode=OUT, javaType=ResultSet, jdbcType=CURSOR, resultMap=VOResultMap}
        )} 
        </select>

    <!-- In the out parameter you need to mention the DTO as it's signature is same as sysrefcursor. 
    There is no difference between sysrefcursor and refcursor except for the creation of the type of refcursor in the proc body or in package -->
    
    <resultMap id="VOResultMap" type="myVO">
            <result property="action" column="ACTION" />
            <result property="id" column="ID" />
            <result property="name" column="NAME" />
    </resultMap>
```

DAO should look like below:

```
public void check(Map response);
```

As the response and request are included in a map there won't be any return type specified in the DAO. Also the response data is tied to the Bean objects list.

Usage:

```
Map responseMap = new HashMap();
responseMap.put("id","identifier");
myDAO.check(responseMap);
List<MyVO> responseList = (List<MyVO>) responseMap.get("myVO");
for (MyVO myVO : responseList) {
    your logic....
}
```